# Can't bind to IPv6 localAddress while using http.get() - Error: bind EINVAL

Tags: node.js, networking, ipv6

I configured my Ubuntu 20.04 server to have multiple IPv6 addresses using `nestat` like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - "xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1/64"
        - "xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64"
      gateway6: "xxxx::1"
      nameservers:
        search: [xxxx.xxxx.com]
        addresses:
          - xxxx:xxxx::6
          - xxxx:xxxx::7
```

I can see these addresses in the output of `ifconfig` and when I ping them using `ping6` on the same server it works.
Now I'm trying to bind to one these IPv6 addresses using `localAddress` and send an HTTP GET request:

```
const http = require('http')

const options = {
    host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    port: 3000,
    path: '/',
    family: 6,
    localAddress: 'xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1'
}

const req = http.get(options)

req.on('response', res => {
    res.on('data', chunk => console.log)
})
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error: bind EINVAL xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::1
```

I understand that this error can mean multiple things:

> The socket is already bound to an address, and the protocol does not
>   support binding to a new address; or the socket has been shut down.

What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue and the answer is trivial - the server I was connecting to simply doesn't support IPv6. If I substitute `host` value with google.com everything works. I wish the error message was more descriptive.